# Calculate field in table A using multiple values from table B in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator

I currently have a point shapefile, and a table.  The tables are set up in a many-to-one relation with "PlotName" as the primary and foreign keys.

The shapefile contains the primary key (i.e. A West H1), the table contains many fields with the same key.

In the table, each row has both a key (PlotName), a value (PercentCover), and whether this value is Native or Invasive (0 or 1).

I would like to create a field in the shapefile (TotalPercentNative) that contains the sum of (PercentCover) based on whether it is native or invasive.

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could run the [Summary Statistics](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/summary-statistics.htm) tool on the table to sum your field, and then join the summary table to the points instead.